# Activity State when getting data from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am getting some data from fragment back to activity using an interface which defines method as :

```
@Override
public void passDataToActivity(String someValue, RecentTransAdapter recentTransAdapter) {
    dateSelected = someValue;
    monthButton.setText(dateSelected);
    mAdapter = recentTransAdapter;
}
```

At what state of activity's lifecycle , this data is received by activity ?

`passDataToActivity()` is being called inside fragment's `onCreateView()`.

The adapter I am getting , I want to use it inside Switch's `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` :

```
aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        Log.d("2^^list is ",String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItemCount()));

        if (!isChecked) {
            Log.d("notchecked","yo");
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
        } else {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter("credit");
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
});
```

Currently this listener code is in activity's `onCreate()`, but the adapter is not what I need to get from fragment.

So at which state this listener needs to be defined to get the required adapter?

Comment: It is called when you call your InterfaceName.passDataToActivity from your fragment

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface like,

```
interface PassDataToActivity{
    void passDataToActivity(String someValue, RecentTransAdapter recentTransAdapter);
}
```

Implement this in your activity

```
public class ActivitySample extends Activity implements PassDataToActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentDemo fragment = FragmentDemo.newInstance();
        fragment.setPassDataToActivityListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void passDataToActivity(String someValue, RecentTransAdapter recentTransAdapter) {
        //Write code here...
        dateSelected = someValue;
        monthButton.setText(dateSelected);
        mAdapter = recentTransAdapter;
    }
}
```

In your fragment you have to define the method to initialize the interface instance and get callback

```
public class FragmentDemo extends Fragment {

    PassDataToActivity mPassDataToActivity;

    public void setPassDataToActivityListener(PassDataToActivity passDataToActivity){
        mPassDataToActivity = passDataToActivity;
    }
}
```

Now, you can pass result to your activity by calling the method

```
mPassDataToActivity.passDataToActivity(someValue,mAdapter);
```

In your situation I think you should pass at the end of `onCheckedChanged()` like,

```
aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        Log.d("2^^list is ",String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItemCount()));

        if (!isChecked) {
            Log.d("notchecked","yo");
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
        } else {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter("credit");
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPassDataToActivity.passDataToActivity(someValue,mAdapter);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When your `Activity` implements a callback listener that will be called by a `Fragment` (similar to what @Jaymin has explained in his answer, your activity is treated just like a Java object instance implementing the callback interface.

> **TL;DR**

The callback is not tied to the `Activity` lifecycle. The `Activity` can be in any step of its lifecycle and will simply receive the callback just like any other Java object.

> **Explanation**

So the `Activity` lifecycle state is in no way related to the implementation of the callback it provides. The callback can be called at anytime and the `Activity`'s implementation will be triggered. If you call it from the `Fragment.onCreateView()` method, it will be called before the `onResume` of the `Activity` as shown below

```
01-10 13:27:01.549 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainActivity: onCreate: called
01-10 13:27:01.678 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainFragment: onCreateView: called
01-10 13:27:01.681 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainActivity: onCallback: called by fragment
01-10 13:27:01.688 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainActivity: onResume: called
01-10 13:27:01.688 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainFragment: onResume: called
```

If you call the callback from `onResume()` of the `Fragment`, it will be called after the `onResume` of the `Activity` as shown below

```
01-10 13:28:55.897 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainActivity: onCreate: called
01-10 13:28:55.926 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainFragment: onCreateView: called
01-10 13:28:55.929 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainActivity: onResume: called
01-10 13:28:55.929 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainFragment: onResume: called
01-10 13:28:55.929 4847-4847/com.c.fragmentlifecycle D/MainActivity: onCallback: called by fragment
```

Hope this helps.